# HashMap adding all items even when duplicate

Tags: java, hashmap

I have been trying without any luck to make a list of all points in a model.  When i execute this

```
    HashList<Point> points=new HashList<Point>(16);

    //add +y side
    points.add(new Point(-5.0,5.0,-5.0));
    points.add(new Point(-5.0,5.0,5.0));
    points.add(new Point(5.0,5.0,5.0));

    points.add(new Point(-5.0,5.0,-5.0));
    points.add(new Point(5.0,5.0,5.0));
    points.add(new Point(5.0,5.0,-5.0));

    //add -x side
    points.add(new Point(-5.0,5.0,-5.0));
    points.add(new Point(-5.0,-5.0,-5.0));
    points.add(new Point(-5.0,-5.0,5.0));

    points.add(new Point(-5.0,5.0,-5.0));
    points.add(new Point(-5.0,-5.0,5.0));
    points.add(new Point(-5.0,5.0,5.0));

    int length=points.length(); //equals 12, 6 expected

    Point a=new Point(-5.0,5.0,-5.0);
    Point b=new Point(-5.0,5.0,-5.0);
    int aHashCode=a.hashCode(); //-737148544
    int bHashCode=b.hashCode(); //-737148544
    boolean equals=a.equals(b); //true
```

points containts 12 points which is the number I started with.  I want all duplicates found which should result in only 6 points in table.

```
if (map.containsKey(e)) {
```

in HashList for some reason never gets executed. Any ideas?

HashList:

```
package dataTypes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashList<E> {
    private HashMap<E,Integer> map;
    private ArrayList<E> data;
    private int count=0;

    public HashList() {
        map=new HashMap<E,Integer>();
        data=new ArrayList<E>();
    }

    public HashList(int size) {
        map=new HashMap<E,Integer>(size);
        data=new ArrayList<E>(size);
    }

    public int add(E e) { //returns key
        if (map.containsKey(e)) {
            return map.get(e);
        } else {
            map.put(e, count);
            data.add(count,e);
            return count++;
        }
    }

    public int getKey(E e) {
        return map.get(e);
    }

    public E get(int key) {
        return data.get(key);
    }

    public int length() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Point:

```
package geometry3D;

/**
 * 3D point location or vector
 * 
 * @author Matthew Cornelisse
 * @version 2014-09-02-004500
 */
public class Point
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Point
     */
    public Point()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }

    public Point(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;
    }
    public Point(Point a) {
        x=a.x;
        y=a.y;
        z=a.z;
    }

    /**
     * Normailizes the point to have distance from center of 1
     *  
     */
    public void normalize()
    {
        // put your code here
        double length=Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
        x/=length;
        y/=length;
        z/=length;
    }



    //implements Shape
    public void rotateX(double angle){
        double newY=Math.cos(angle)*y-Math.sin(angle)*z;
        double newZ=Math.sin(angle)*y+Math.cos(angle)*z;
        y=newY;
        z=newZ;
    }
    public void rotateY(double angle){
        double newX=Math.cos(angle)*x-Math.sin(angle)*z;
        double newZ=Math.sin(angle)*x+Math.cos(angle)*z;
        x=newX;
        z=newZ;
    }
    public void rotateZ(double angle){
        double newX=Math.cos(angle)*x-Math.sin(angle)*y;
        double newY=Math.sin(angle)*x+Math.cos(angle)*y;
        x=newX;
        y=newY;
    }
    public void rotate(Vector axis, double angle){
        //source:  http://inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/
        double oldX=x;
        double oldY=y;
        double oldZ=z;
        double sinA=Math.sin(angle);
        double cosA=Math.cos(angle);
        Point offset=axis.offset();
        Point vector=axis.vector();
        double u=vector.x;
        double v=vector.y;
        double w=vector.z;
        double a=offset.x;
        double b=offset.y;
        double c=offset.z;


        x=(a*(v*v+w*w)-u*(b*v+c*w-u*oldX-v*oldY-w*oldZ))*(1-cosA)+oldX*cosA+(-c*v+b*w-w*oldY+v*oldZ)*sinA;
        y=(b*(u*u+w*w)-v*(a*u+c*w-u*oldX-v*oldY-w*oldZ))*(1-cosA)+oldY*cosA+(c*u-a*w+w*oldX-u*oldZ)*sinA;
        z=(c*(u*u+v*v)-w*(a*u+b*v-u*oldX-v*oldY-w*oldZ))*(1-cosA)+oldZ*cosA+(-b*u+a*v-v*oldX+u*oldY)*sinA;



    }
    public void move(double x, double y, double z){
        this.x+=x;
        this.y+=y;
        this.z+=z;
    }
    public void move(Vector direction,double magnitude){
        this.x+=(direction.vector().x*magnitude);
        this.y+=(direction.vector().y*magnitude);
        this.z+=(direction.vector().z*magnitude);
    }

    public boolean equals(Point compare) {
        if (Math.abs(compare.x-x)>5*Math.ulp(compare.x)) return false;
        if (Math.abs(compare.y-y)>5*Math.ulp(compare.y)) return false;
        if (Math.abs(compare.z-z)>5*Math.ulp(compare.z)) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean equals(Point compare, double error) {
        if (Math.abs(compare.x-x)>error) return false;
        if (Math.abs(compare.y-y)>error) return false;
        if (Math.abs(compare.z-z)>error) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        Double a=(Double)x;
        Double b=(Double)y;
        Double c=(Double)z;
        return a.hashCode()^Integer.rotateRight(b.hashCode(),12)^Integer.rotateRight(c.hashCode(),24);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object compare) {
        try {
            Point temp=(Point)compare;
            if (temp.x!=x) return false;
            if (temp.y!=y) return false;
            if (temp.z!=z) return false;
            return true;
        } finally {
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `Set`?

Comment: Aside from anything else, using `try/finally` like that in your `equals` method is *horrible*. Use `instanceof` instead.

Comment: Next, please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We shouldn't have to start adding the code to create equal points etc. (Note that almost all the code in `Point` is irrelevant to the question, as you're not rotating any points etc.)

Comment: This won't work! The hashCode() method uses the hashCode() of Double Objects, which is (almost unique for every double object evenen if the values are equal. The same problem with the equals method, you compare the objects instances with each other here, not the values. Use double primitives instead of objects. You need to compare the values like 'if(Math.abs(a-b) < 0.00001)' then they are equal. I don't know any way how to construct a hash value from doubles where the hashvalue is an int. I would suggest to use a 'TreeSet' which uses the equals method or a custom Comarator

Comment: Why dont use try with a smaller subset of data with some duplicate elements and debug your hashCode/equals method? Most likely you might need tweaks to either of these methods.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I added a test script made up of 2 sides of a cube as they would normally get entered(2 triangles per side).  @Westranger I am looking for the points to be exactly the same.  as you can see from my `public boolean equals(Point compare) {` I am well aware of the need to look for close points but the points I am looking for in this sercumstance should be exactly the same.

Comment: @Neo if you look at my test code above you can see that creating 2 points a & b result in values that should work.

Comment: I've found the problem now, but it would have been easier if you'd produced a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I had to remove irrelevant bits of `Point` to get it to compile, as well as putting the "test script" in a class etc. In an ideal question, I should be able to copy/paste/compile.

Comment: @Jon Skeet thank you.  next time I will post code so it can be executed.  Is there any way to upload a project file with all necessary libraries?  or do I have to post that on my own server and link it?

Comment: @MatthewCornelisseq: It's very rarely necessary to have so much code that you can't just post it all... certainly the amount that's needed here is small enough: for `Point` you just need a single constructor, the `hashCode` and `equals` methods, and for `HashList` you only need the `add` and `length` methods. Basically, cut things down as much as you can until there's nothing else you can remove without breaking the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `finally` block in `equals(Object)`. It's *always* returning `false`, even if you're returning `true` from the `try` block.

You're getting confused because of this:

```
boolean equals=a.equals(b); //true
```

... but that's not calling the same `equals` method - it's calling `equals(Point)`.

Your `equals(Object)` method should be written as:

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object compare) {
    if (compare == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (compare == null || compare.getClass() != getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Point temp = (Point) compare; // Guaranteed to work now
    return temp.x == x && temp.y == y && temp.z == z;
}
```

Note that:

- As noted elsewhere, you can't come up with an equality/hash which handles tolerance... if you do any significant arithmetic with these points, you're unlikely to have exact equality any more
- Your class has public fields, which is pretty much *always* a bad idea
- Your class is mutable, which is a bad idea from the point of view of code using the hash code - collections are *much* easier to use correctly when the element type is immutable
- If you make your class `final`, you can use `instanceof` instead of the `getClass()` check - and again, that would help prevent someone introducing a mutable subclass. (Equality relationships across an inheritance hierarchy are generally painful anyway.)

Comment: i renamed my 2 other equals functions to almostEquals and implemented this and it worked perfectly.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed by rolfl, it is no use to try to use java equals method to compare Points with an acceptable error (see TL/DR section below if you are in doubt).

So, you have to do it the hard way. Do not even imagine to use `map.containsKey(e)`, but create an explicit method in `HashList`. I would begin by that interface :

```
public interface DistEquality<E> {
    boolean distEquals(E compare);
}
```

Then declare  `Point` to implement it :

```
public class Point implements DistEquality<Point> {
    ...
    public static double defaultError = 10E-3;
    @Override
    public boolean distEquals(Point compare) {
        return equals(compare, defaultError);
    }
}
```

And modify HashList that way

```
public class HashList<E  extends DistEquality<E>> {
    ...
    public int distValue(E e) {
        for (Entry<E, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.distEquals(entry.getKey())) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int add(E e) { //returns key
        int pos = distValue(e);
        if (pos != -1) {
            return pos;
        } else {
            map.put(e, count);
            data.add(count,e);
            return count++;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I have not tested anything, but I think the general idea should be Ok.

TL/DR
Below solution is plain wrong - (thanks to rolfl to noticing)

The `equals` method in class `Point` requires exact equality of doubles. You should instead have a `static double defaultError` in `Point` class, initialized at an appropriate value and then do :

```
public boolean equals(Object compare) {
    return ((compare instanceof Point) ? equals(compare, defaultError) : false);
}
```

But as noticed by rolfl, this is not enough, because javadoc for `Object.hashCode()` states *If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result*.

It would be very hard to imagine an intelligent hash compatible with the above equality method. Worse, once one point gets a hashCode value, any other point is at a finite number of `defaultError` and you can imagine a finished suite of Points that are all 2 per 2 equals and so hashCode should be a constant.

Worse, as equals is required to be reflexive, symetric and transitive, all Points should be equal.

It looks that the idea of using equal that way is really a **bad** idea :-(

Comment: This is only a part answer. Modifying equals without also modifying hashCode will not help

Comment: @rolfl: you are right, but even equals method does not respect JDK contract - see my edit

Comment: I am new to java but would not this modification cause the class to not work on other object types?  The class is generic and should be usable on all object types.  Also in this specific instance the points I am looking for are exactly the same as they should all have come into existence from the same point set(a cube for example has only 8 points but requires 36 points to model it as triangles.)  Once entered into the software the points should all get manipulated in exactly the same way so they should all continue to have the same value exactly not approximately.

Comment: This doesn't answer why the *exact* double values are still causing duplicates.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse : the reason why *exact* double values are still causing duplicates is given in Jon Skeet's answer. As you defined an *almost equals* method in class `Point` I was trying to imagine how to use it. The modified class would work on any other class implementing a `distEquals` method. That mean that you probably would have to wrap existing classes to implement it, or change the logic and use an `AlmostEqualsComparator` class like `compare` can use `Comparable` classes or `Comparator`.

Comment: thanks for the help. Jon Skeet's answer(which is unfortunetly below this) works perfectly.  My almost equals funtions where actually causing the problem to some extent as this would not work at all with them named equals.  so renaming and implementing his function fixes everything.

Answer (score 0):

The HashList implementation is incorrect if you want it to be able to contain duplicates. On your add, if the map already has the key, you just return the value..., so your duplicates will never get inserted.

If you are getting duplicates, that means that your Equals/HashCode for Point is likely screwed up.

Right now, your HashList doesnt actually allow duplicates, so you might as well just get rid of it and use a HashSet from java collections. Also, get a decent java IDE like netbeans, eclipse, IntellIJ and have it generate the equals/hashcode for you on your point class.

Comment: I do not want to get duplicates.  The problem is I am getting duplicates

Comment: Also I am using eclipse

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, then why don't you just use a HashSet? In any case, it is very likely that there is something wrong with your HashCode/Equals implementation. Try adding those items to a HashSet and see if you still get dups. If you do, you will know your Equals/HashCode is messed up.

Comment: This has been fixed now(see answer).  Not using HashSet because I need to go both ways and need a known index